# Can we check whether s3 bucket is currently accessed via http in any 1 of the account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, https

As part of the compliance, we need to Ensure S3 Bucket Policy is set to deny HTTP requests;

before that Can we check whether s3 bucket is currently accessed via http in any 1 of the account.

Can we check whether s3 bucket is currently accessed via http in any 1 of the account.

Comment: Amazon S3 buckets are private by default. If you have not assigned a Bucket Policy, then the bucket can only be accessed by IAM users that have permission to access the bucket. You can [Log requests with server access logging - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ServerLogs.html) to collect information about objects being accessed.